# Salesforce communities: Issues with Using Custom Stylesheets and SLDS

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, napili

**Background:**
We currently have several lightning components our community that reference several static resources. To load the static resources, I am using `<ltng:require>` component.

**Issue:**
Let's assume that I use Salesforce Lightning Design System in one on my components. So I load it using `<ltng:require>`. Then, place this in one of my pages on the community, let's say on `Home` , then i create another page `Group` and have place some more components on this page which can be standard or custom. Now if i access the `Group` page from `Home`, some of the styles from the stylesheets loaded in `Home` page are being set to components on this page.

Scenario:
I visit the community and I am routed to the `Home` Page, now open the Sources tab in Chrome Devtools and check the resources that are loaded, we have the Salesforce Design System loaded.
[image]

Now I go the new page and inspect the components to see what CSS properties are applied, and i see that a few of the properties from the lightning design system are added to the component on this page.

Now this is an issue if I go to the `Home` Page and then go to the `Group` Page. If i visit the `Group` Page directly, I have no issue of this kind, because the resource was never loaded.

Because of this, CSS appplied is very inconsistent and is causing a few issues. In the example below i go the page directly, there is no issue. Buf if i launch the same page by first going to Home Page, one of the buttons in the modal has a different color applied to it.

Example:
[image]

Some more info on the org:

Community Template: Napili

Version : Winter 17.

Locker Service : Not Enabled.

Access Check Critical Update: Enabled